# How can I encrypt/decrypt data in the database automatically

Tags: php, encryption

Is there anyway in PHP to automatically encrypt and decrypt data to/from the database?

Right now, I'm using SSL and other security mesures to protect my application but data stored in the database is still in plain text. Is there anyway to automatically store it in encrypted form so that data isn't plain text anymore?

Comment: see when we serve data stored in db we use ssl and other security options.  But when the data is just sitting in the DB its not encrypted.  Like you can see the name the way it is etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encrypting for the sake of encrypting is useless. Databases are filled with non-sensitive information that doesn't need to be encrypted. Just make sure that your DB server is properly secured by a strong password and relevant firewall rules (to prevent outside access).

Encrypting everything would remove the ability to properly query the database as you would always have to query based on the encrypted form. So you can forget things like `ORDER BY` (which would be meaningless) and easy `WHERE` clauses.

That said, you still need to properly hash (bcrypt) your passwords **AND secret answers** (this is largely forgotten, unfortunately) and secure any sensitive data such as SSNs. That can be done manually in your Model class.

The reason why these informations are encrypted/hashed versus normal information is that in case of an SQL injection attacks, proper hashing makes it close to impossible for attackers to gain further access to the system (versus plain text passwords which can be then used to gain access to the service).

Comment: Sure, we have firewalls and log monitoring.  But i want to add this as a 3rd measure in case a breach goes that far.  Plus companies like box.net use it and other people use it, how will they be able to do it?

Comment: @AAA: **They encrypt only the files' binary data**, not the whole database, and that's an important point. Binary data will never be used in a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause. What they do is probably encrypt/decrypt it on the fly in their Model class. If you are to encrypt part of your database, you have to **be very selective** on the rows you choose to encrypt. If you are not selective, you need to do your ordering and querying on the application side...